# MongoDB Convert Array of Objects to Single Object

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Using a MongoDB aggregate query, how do I convert an array of documents to a single document. The array can have N number of documents.

**Before**

```
"loop" : [
    {
        "field1" : "1"
    }, 
    {
        "field2" : "2", 
        "field3" : "3", 
    }, 
    {
        "field4" : "4", 
    }, 
    {
        "field5" : "5", 
        "field6" : "6"
    }
]
```

**After**

```
"loop" : {
    "field1" : "1",
    "field2" : "2", 
    "field3" : "3", 
    "field4" : "4", 
    "field5" : "5", 
    "field6" : "6"
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use below aggregation in 3.6 and above.

```
db.colname.aggregate(
 [{"$project":{
    "loop":{
      "$reduce":{
        "input":"$loop",
        "initialValue":{},
        "in":{"$mergeObjects":["$$value","$$this"]
        }
      }
    }
 }}]
)
```

Comment: Please, help
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55013224/mongo-db-request-in-java-spring-data-mongo

Answer (score 3):

Based on Veeram's answer above using $mergeObjects, here's a more concise query using $project.

**Query**

```
db.loop.aggregate(
    [{
        "$project": {
            "loop": { $mergeObjects: "$loop" }
        }
    }]
)
```

**Result**

```
{ 
    "loop" : {
        "field1" : "1", 
        "field2" : "2", 
        "field3" : "3", 
        "field4" : "4", 
        "field5" : "5", 
        "field6" : "6"
    }
}
```

Comment: This also works for older MongoDb version. Specifically, I have 3.0.6.