# Mongo DB request in Java Spring-data Mongo

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I have an array inside of document.

```
{
    "id" : "id_1",
    "name" : "name_1";
    "additionalData" : [
        {
             "additionalDataId" : "id_1_1",
             "additionalDataName" : "name_1_1",
             "longText" : "A long story about..."  
        },
        {
             "additionalDataId" : "id_1_2",
             "additionalDataName" : "name_1_2",
             "longText" : "A longer story about danger..."  
        },
        {
             "additionalDataId" : "id_1_3",
             "additionalDataName" : "name_1_3",
             "longText" : "A longer story about danger and courage"  
        },
    ]       
}
```

To retrieve element of array with name `"name_1_2"`, I use mongo query.

```
db.collection.find( { name: "name_1"},
        { _id: 0, additionalData: { $elemMatch: { "additionalDataName": "name_1_2" } } 
    })
```

How to do the same using `mongoTemplate`?

I have tried

```
Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(
    Aggregation.match(
            Criteria.where("name").is("name_1").and("additionalData.additionalDataName").is("name_1_2")
        ),
    Aggregation.project("additionalData"),
```

);
mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, "CustmObjects", Object.class);

And I also tried to use `ArrayOperators.Filter.filter`, I used this answer.

```
Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(
        Aggregation.match(Criteria.where("name").is("name_1")),
        Aggregation.project("additionalData").and(
                ArrayOperators.Filter.filter("additionalData").as("item")
                        .by(ComparisonOperators.valueOf("item.additionalDataName").equalTo("name_1_2"))
        )
    );
mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, "CustmObjects", Object.class);
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/46769125/4587961

Anyway, the result I got, all elements of the array.
Please, help!

Comment: `$elemMatch` projection is not available in `aggregate()`. Use a `.find` variant instead, or `$filter` just as demonstrated in the answers you link to.

Comment: I will write in 9 hours. Not at work now. It did not work with `Aggregate` and `ArrayOperators.Filter`

Comment: Okay, better to actually show what you tried so we can point out what exactly you did wrong anyway. Though I thought I did previously link you to a spring-mongo implementation of exactly that `$filter` usage. So a bit unsure what part you did not get right. Either that or I linked the wrong example :(

Comment: @NeilLunn I updated.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood the question correctly, this will give the desired results.

```
Query query = new Query(new Criteria().andOperator(
    Criteria.where("name").is("name_1"),
    Criteria.where("additionalData.additionalDataName").is("name_1_2")
));
query.fields().include("additionalData").exclude("_id");

List<Document> results = template.find(query, collectionName, org.bson.Document.class);
```

Comment: This is giving a list but question is to fetch this object - {
             "additionalDataId" : "id_1_2",
             "additionalDataName" : "name_1_2",
             "longText" : "A longer story about danger..."  
        }